# Redirecting page on 401 status code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm setting up authorization with AngularJS and angular ui router.
If a user tries to access a route which requires authorization, the server returns a 401 status code.

I have created an HTTP response interceptor which checks for the 401 status code.
If the code is 401, it is supposed to redirect to the log in page, but this does not work.
It catches the 401, but does not redirect. Here is the code for the interceptor:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    // This is just for to check for XHR requests on the server
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(

                // Success: just return the response
                function (response) {
                    return response;
                },

                // Error: check the error status to get only the 401
                function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401)
                        $location.url('/users/login');

                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            );
        }
    }]);
}]);
```

EDIT: It seems to be working if I do it like this:

`$timeout(function() { $location.url('/users/login'); }, 0);`

I guess that puts it last in the execution stack and changes the execution context. Does anyone know more about this, or if this indeed does work or only seems so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, but I still don't know why it didn't work. Anyway, I had to use this to redirect: (state transition)

`$injector.get('$state').transitionTo('users.login');`

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue. So I changed my code to use the $location.path (not url)

```
 $location.path("/users/login");
```

Can you try that

```
angular.module('yourApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {

  var logsOutUserOn401 = ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
    var success = function (response) {
      return response;
    };

    var error = function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        //redirect them back to login page
        $location.path('/login');

        return $q.reject(response);
      } 
      else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };

    return function (promise) {
      return promise.then(success, error);
    };
  }];

  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(logsOutUserOn401);
});
```

(source : http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I suspect it might have something to do with either the execution context, the return statement, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with

```
$window.location.href='...'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how we added a response interceptor in our project. its working for us.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope, $location,
                                        $cookieStore) {
                                    return {
                                        'responseError' : function(
                                                rejection) {
                                            var status = rejection.status;
                                            var config = rejection.config;
                                            var method = config.method;
                                            var url = config.url;

                                            if (status == 401) {

                                                $rootScope.shouldRedirect = true;
                                                $rootScope.urlAttempted = url;

                                                $location
                                                        .path("/login");

                                            } else if (status == 403) {

                                                $location
                                                        .path("/accessForbidden");

                                            } else {

                                            }

                                            return $q.reject(rejection);
                                        }
                                    };
                                });
```